# Analysing clojure programs' dependencies

Tags: clojure

I have multiple (3k+) scripts written in clojure (each script doesn't depend on any other).
These scripts are written in Clojure 1.2, and I want to analyse them in terms of old contrib libraries used. So far I am simply grepping files for occurences of `clojure.contrib\.[0-9a-z\.\-]*`, but I would also like to find specific functions from these contrib libraries that are used inside my scripts.

Is there a better way to do this than regular expressions?

Any clojure libraries that would allow me to parse string (containing Clojure program) and easily extract dependencies?

Comment: If you are using Lein, they try lein deps :tree for some inspiration

Comment: [slamhound](https://github.com/technomancy/slamhound) performs similar kinds of analyses. Might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [core.analyze](https://github.com/frenchy64/analyze) you may be able to get nearer.

This is an old example I have which will give you all top level functions/elements of each project file.

You should be able to easily modify the `parse-clojure-file` function to analyze the function tree to check for invocations.

Setup dependencies using `leiningen.core.project` and `analyze.core`:

```
(ns dependencies.project
  (:require
   [leiningen.core.project :as project]
   [analyze.core :as analyze]
   [clojure.java.io])
  (:import
   (java.io PushbackReader)))
```

Read file from disk and process

```
(defn parse-clojure-file
  "Reads a clojure source file from disk
   and returns a sequence of hashes of
   first level objects
     {:type defn :name parse-clojure-file}
     {:type ns :name clandombg.project}
     ..."
  [file]
  (let [forms (analyze.core/forms-seq
               (java.io.PushbackReader. (clojure.java.io/reader file)))]
    (reduce (fn [file-obj form]
              (conj file-obj {:type (first form) :name (second form)}))
        [] forms)))
```

Tree of all project files, the returned hash-map is indexed by relative path:

```
(defn traverse-source-tree
  "Traverses a source directory recursively and returns
  a collection of files keyed by relative-path and content
  the file first level objects"
  [directory]
  (let [files (file-seq (clojure.java.io/file directory))
        clj-files (filter #(re-matches #".+\.clj$|.+\.cljs$" (.getName %)) files)]
    (reduce (fn [project file]
              (let [relative-path (clojure.string/replace (.getPath file) directory "")]
                (assoc project
                  relative-path
                  (merge
                   (parse-clojure-file file)
                   {:relative-path relative-path}))))
            {} clj-files)))
```

Entry point:

```
(defn parse-project
  "Reads a project file from disk and parses its source
  files, returns a clojure encoded string"
  [project-path]
  (let [project (project/read project-path)]
    (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (traverse-source-tree %2))
                          {}
                          (:source-paths project))))
```

Invoke with:

```
(parse-project "path/to/project.clj")
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice, but after all I did it with regular expressions (my scripts had lots of ":use" imports, so I would have to evaluate them to properly resolve all functions' namespaces).